# Learn proper programming syles?

Tags: coding-style

Where would one find information or just rather good ideas on what is considered proper programming ethics or methodology of how to format the code, comments, or even variable names so that it is easier to read the code at a later time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The book [Code Complete 2](http://www.cc2e.com/) is a timeless reference for good coding practice.

Comment: I keep hearing about this book. Maybe the time will soon come I will actually make the purchase. +1

Comment: For those who have read both 1 and 2, would it be helpful for a mid level developer to read the first one before jumping to the second?

Comment: Thanks for this! I am going to check this book out , as well as the information from the posts below. Thanks guys!

Comment: I would suggest you only need Code Complete 2 its a revision of the original Code Complete. It presents the concepts in the context of modern languages we use today.

Answer (score 8):

The absolute 'must-read' for you is [Robert C. Martin's book Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). Do give it a try. It makes some awesome points. I keep recommending to everyone ever since I bought it 6 months ago.

**Edit**

I thought reading [my Amazon review](http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R3V1L3L23H85II/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm) could help :)

Comment: see http://web.telia.com/~u43518104/reviews/cleancode.htm and http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1844 for less enthusiastic reviews

Comment: +1 to your comment. I totally forgot to mention the book IS all about Java and OOP. But the concepts covered are widely applicable and I wish all of my colleagues would have read this book. It's just... enlightening.

Comment: Another review http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2009/04/22/book-review-clean-code/

Comment: again, +1 for the comment. I had a look at the review and... Yes, the book really is divided into two parts, one more interesting than the other. The second half of the book contains a bit too many code examples, but that's okay. No one will ever force you to read the whole thing. The first 190 pages contain such good points I wish everyone would read and consider to apply the knowledge in their everyday hacking.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out! Great review also!!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for Coding Standards, which are language specific.

For C# check out [The IDesign C# Coding Standard](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx) (on the right-side of the screen in the middle of the page)

For .NET in general see [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)

For C++ check  [here](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html)

For Java see Sun's resource [Code Conventions for the JavaTM Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

For C++ I use [the C++ google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Including Code Complete and Clean Code I would recommend you to read "The pragmatic programmer" and "Ship it!". The last books mentioned are not so much about how to format the code, comments, ect. but rather about best practices for developers and development.

Answer (score 0):

Three books I consider essential for beginning OO programmers.

1. "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code".

Although modern IDEs often support automatic refactor, this book is still useful. By knowing the reason (or code smell) behind a particular refacoring, you can strive to write the correct code the first time.

2. "Pragmatic Programmer"

A wealth of best practices.

3. "Design Pattern"

Most advanced book, but still useful.

Comment: Pragmatic Programmer is not an advanced book.   It has simple and clear advice like:  "Learn to use a really good editor."  and "Use revision control"  and talks about the principle of "No broken windows".  These are basic concepts that can be considered as easily by a damp behind the ears newb as a by a grizzled gray beard.  Both should read and think deeply about the principles laid out in this book.

Answer (score 0):

Clean Code is certainly a good book. Martin's *Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#* is my recommendation if you want a more .NET specific book.